# Why do CSS div dimensions differ from Devtools dimensions?

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I am testing responsiveness in my react app and I have come across a pretty confusing issue while working with my devtools console. The width of the element I am working with is `768px`. These are the same dimensions for a tablet screen. However, the element width only covers part of the screen as shown in the screenshot below.
[image: Devtools dimensions]

Where is this extra space on the right coming from? I believe the element should cover the entire width of the screen since the dimensions are equal. I have also in my CSS file:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

My full CSS file looks like this:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Akaya+Telivigala&display=swap");

.projects {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.indivProject {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 900px 120px;
}

.projImage img {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .projects {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 60px;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .projects {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 60px;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.project-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 180px;
  margin-top: 240px;
}

.tech {
  margin-left: 250px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: rgb(9, 150, 79);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .project-text {
    margin-left: 80px;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .project-text {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .projImage img {
    display: none;
  }
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(9, 150, 79);
}

a:hover {
  color: saddlebrown;
}

h4 {
  color: rgb(15, 89, 102);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

The corresponding markup looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import nutri from '../../images/nutri.png';
import akan from '../../images/akan.png';
import convo from '../../images/convo.png';

function Projects(){
    return (
      
    <div className="projects">
        <h4>HIGHLIGHTED PROJECTS</h4>

        <div data-aos="zoom-out" className="indivProject">
            <div data-aos="zoom-out" className="project-text">
                <p>
                    <h3><a href="https://happy-davinci-4bd16c.netlify.app/">TEXTR</a></h3>
                    This is a mobile-responsive messaging app built using React and leverages the use of ChatEngine to provide an interactive communication experience. Hosted on Netlify.
                </p>
                <ul className="tech">
                    <li>React</li>
                    <li>Chat Engine</li>
                    <li>React Testing Library</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div className="projImage"><img src={convo} alt=""></img></div>
        </div>

        <div data-aos="zoom-out" className="indivProject">
            <div data-aos="zoom-out" className="project-text">
                <p>
                    <h3><a href="https://damian-sketch.github.io/NutriCrew/">NUTRIAPP</a></h3>
                    This is an application that acts more like a remote doctor. By inputing some personal data such as Weight, Height and Physical activity, the user reveives ther caloric intake recommendation and is able to evaluate their health status.
                </p>
                <ul className="tech">
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>CSS</li>
                    <li>JavaScript</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div className="projImage"><img src={nutri} alt=""></img></div>
        </div>

        <div data-aos="zoom-out" className="indivProject">
            <div data-aos="zoom-out" className="project-text">
                <p>
                    <h3><a href="https://damian-sketch.github.io/Birthday/">AKAN NAMES</a></h3>
                    Akan names are derived from Ghanian culture. Frequently in Ghana, children are given their first name as a 'day name' which corresponds to the day in the week they were born. This application will help you identify an Akan name based on the time you were born.
                </p>    
                <ul className="tech">
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>CSS</li>
                    <li>JavaScript</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div className="projImage"><img src={akan} alt=""></img></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    )
}


export default Projects;
```

I have tried restarting my devtools but still no resolve.

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a representative sample of your markup and CSS.

Comment: The shift on the right seems to correspond to the margin on the left. Without seeing your structure I can't say anything more.

Comment: I have provided the markup and styliing files @isherwood

Comment: I'm asking for HTML, not JSX. You can create a simple demo with the editor. It should not include fonts, color styles, etc.